# PostgreSQL как преобразовать bytea в guid

Tags: postgresql, кодировка

Есть поле в таблице с типом bytea. Нужно правильно его переобразовать в guid.
Сами данные в поле - `]\213\000\036\311\353\323\341\021\345\203\272Lw\376\206`
Конвертирую в uuid следующим образом:

```
select encode(']\213\000\036\311\353\323\341\021\345\203\272Lw\376\206', 'hex') :: uuid
```

На выходе получаю: `5d8b001e-c9eb-d3e1-11e5-83ba4c77fe86`
Как-бы вроде, то что нужно. Но guid должен быть вида: `4c77fe86-83ba-11e5-5d8b-001ec9ebd3e1`. Если присмотреться, то сам запрос encode почему-то меняет части гуида местами. Почему это происходит и как получить нужный мне формат?

Comment: как можно заметить по показанному bytea - encode ничего не меняет в порядке. Первый байт как был `5d` (acsii символ `]`) - так и остался. Почему вы считаете, что должен быть uuid как показали вы?

Comment: @Мелкий Работаю с 1с. Пытаюсь сделать загрузку данных из xml. При выгрузки из 1с id сотрудника показывает `4c77fe86-83ba-11e5-5d8b-001ec9ebd3e1`, а вот у меня получается, при encode получается `5d8b001e-c9eb-d3e1-11e5-83ba4c77fe86`. Вот отсюда тогда и вопрос как это так.

Comment: Ищите где искажаются данные. Не здесь. Конвертация с сохранением порядка байт корректна.

Comment: Да уже думаю пойти более простым путём (наверное). Выгрузить всех сотрудников в xml и оттуда тянуть их guid. И не заморачиваться с encode. Было просто интересно почему так происходит.